# Could not get unknown property 'classpath' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm building Ionic app to Android device. My gradle version is 3.3. I'm a first timer to this Android building. I got following error:

```
Build file 'E:\FarmApp\smartFarm\platforms\android\build.gradle' line: 33

    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
    > Could not get unknown property 'classpath' for object of type
    org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

My build.gradle file section follows

```
 buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

// Switch the Android Gradle plugin version requirement depending on the
// installed version of Gradle. This dependency is documented at
// http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility
// and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8143
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3',
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
}
}

 // Allow plugins to declare Maven dependencies via build-extras.gradle.
allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenCentral();
    jcenter()
  }
 }

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
gradleVersion = '2.14.1'
}
```

Comment: You said your gradle version is `3.3` but in your code there's this line `gradleVersion = '2.14.1'`

Comment: i change gradle version to gradleVersion = '3.3' and then 3.3.0 still same error. Should i change classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3', that is the line 33.

Comment: according to https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle `2.3.3` is the latest stable version.. Try changing to that

Comment: Same error even after changing to 2.3.3

Comment: try removing the `android` platform from ionic and then adding it back again

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved my day. Removing the android platform from ionic and then adding it back again works

Comment: Glad to hear it went well :). I submitted an answer if anyone else encounters the problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the `android` platform from `ionic` and then adding it back again with the following commands

```
   $ ionic platform remove android
   $ ionic platform add android
```

Answer (score 26):

Remove the comma at the end of classpath. This worked for me.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
}
```

Comment: This is defently the correct answer, i think that happens when a JS/TS Dev starts to work with Flutter and is used to JSON